# What is state object in setSearchParams hook react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, query-string

what is { state: ? } in the update function of useSearchParams.

```
  const [search, setSearch] = useSearchParams();
  setSearch(
    {
      ...Object.fromEntries(search),
      transFilters: JSON.stringify(filters),
    },
    { state: filters }
  );
```

I have searched a lot on the internet but I didn't any documentation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state is the same state that you could/would pass as with the `navigate` function. From the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) docs:

> Note
>
> The `setSearchParams` function works like `navigate`, but only for the
> search portion of the URL. Also note that ***the second arg to
> `setSearchParams` is the same type as the second arg to navigate***.

See the `NavigateOptions` type:

> ```
> interface NavigateOptions {
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   preventScrollReset?: boolean;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
More information in https://reach.tech/router/api/navigate#:~:text=An%20object%20to%20store%20on%20location%20state.%20This%20is%20useful%20for%20state%20that%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20need%20to%20be%20in%20the%20URL%20but%20is%20associated%20with%20a%20route%20transition.%20Think%20of%20it%20like%20%E2%80%9Cpost%E2%80%9D%20data%20on%20a%20server.